# How to set document viewer default application?

Tags: 16.04, pdf, file-association, document

I tried to set document viewer default application.

[image: Problem Screenshot]

Comment: What happened when you clicked "Set as default" ?

Comment: Looks good so far. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: ImageMagick no change when I click set as default

Comment: Suggest : Install `evince` , and use it for PDF, PostScript, DjVu, TIFF, XPS and DVI . ... ImageMagick has a viewer command :  `display file.jpg` . ImageMagick is for images  https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=imagemagick+viewer ( can open some pdf ? )

Answer (score 0):

Below is the procedure that helped me in resolving this annoying problem.

By Mina Michael:

> You don't need to delete the file and lose all the associations. You
>   could just remove the lines that associate PDF to imagemagick. I just
>   removed the following lines from ~/.config/mimeapps.list, and it
>   worked!
>
> image/pdf=display-im6.desktop
>
> image/pdf=display-im6.q16.desktop;display-im6.desktop;

Regards,
Attique

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Say, would you mind adding some attribution here?  A link to Mina Michael's work and perhaps his profile too would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Attique, for posting this solution! It is the first that pointed me to the correct file >>>>>
        ~/.config/mimeapps.list

---

I wanted to associate tiff and tif files with the ImageJ application.
- I first created an ImageJ.desktop file in /usr/share/applications/ with the following contents:

```
 Version=1.0

 Name=ImageJ

 Comment=ImageJ Launcher

 Exec=/home/vanmetter/.ImageJ/ImageJ

 Icon=/home/vanmetter/.ImageJ/images/icon.png

 Terminal=false

 Type=Application

 Categories=Utility;Application;
```

(see other posts for how to create .desktop files)

- I then added:

  image/tiff=ImageJ.desktop

  image/tif=ImageJ.desktop

  to the [Defaults Applications] section of ~/.config/mimeapps.list. Choose either the [Default Applications] section or the [Added Associations] section as desired.

Now, my tiff and tif files open (double click) with ImageJ as the default program. If I had used the [Added Associations] section, I would right-click on the file and ImageJ would be offered as an alternate application to open tiff and tif files.